# Draw transparent rectangles without intersection area in Matlab

Tags: matlab, intersection, rectangles

I would like to draw a lot of rectangles in Matlab. I know I can use "rectangle" command to draw any shape of rectangle I want. However, when there are two rectangles with intersection, it stills shows rectangles' lines within the overlapping area
[image]

Is there any way to draw without those lines in the intersection area like the following graph? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I would recommend using [`PolygonClip`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8818-polygon-clipper) for performing this operation.

Comment: A hacky solution might be to find intersections and draw white bordered rectangle covering this inside part, then draw black dots on the intersections.

Comment: if you can find all corners and intersection points, and eliminate the corners that appear inside another rectangle, you can then use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679053/4183191

Comment: Transplant? You mean transparent? if so my answer not gonna help you.

Answer (score 1):

As I guess you mean transparent ones, then this solution would be desired:

```
%set the coordinates of your t-shaped polygon considering order of plotting points:
x=[0 2 2 6 6 2 2 0 0];
y=[0 0 1 1 3 3 4 4 0];
plot(x,y)  % to plot polygon
```

---

---

This would be the output:

[image: T-shape polygon]